# Java web service client log in and log out page

Tags: java, web-services, webservice-client

I have to create a java web service. I have no idea on how to do this. I have done the calculator exercise but it seems like its more complicated when it comes to dealing with strings and JFrames, as the return value in this case has to be a page(JFrame)

Can someone give me a little hint on how to get started please!!!!!
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java web services are APIs which are exposed over the web, typically SOAP/XML-RPC/REST. The latter is all the rage. The former two use XML exclusively and the latter uses XML and REST.

Typically they don't have a graphical user interface as they form part of a web app, usually deployed through a web application container, like Jetty / Tomcat / JBoss etc.

I would start here: http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html

Comment: Okay i have made some progress i have created a web service that reads an xml file and its nodes (username and password) how can i get an input from a user and compare it to the web service strings?